# When to Call JavaScript Toggle Function?

Tags: javascript

I have a drop down menu I need to make appear and disappear using pure JavaScript (no libraries/jQuery).  Thus I am developing a toggle function.  However despite trying several approaches, nothing seems to work. My current idea is to create a variable to hold the state of the menu (open or closed).  Once the display of the menu changes from "none" to "block", the variable should change from "closed" to "open".  Then an event listener would be added to the body element so when anything is clicked, the menu closes (i.e. the display property is changed back to "none").

Unfortunately the above doesn't seem work.  When I put the If/else block outside of an event listener it fires when the page loads, but not when the menuToggle variable changes.  If I put it or a function inside the menuPlaceholder event listener the menu won't open, probably due to the open and close code being called basically at the same time.

Clearly I am missing something, probably related to program control or function calling.  Does anyone have any insights?

The code I am working with is below. Note the alert functions peppered throughout the code are for testing purposes only.

```js
//Puts IDs for search preference selection box into variables
 var menuPlaceholder = document.getElementById('searchSelection');
 var menuDisplay = document.getElementById('searchOptions');
 var boxLabel = document.getElementById('searchLabel');
 
 //Puts IDs for text input box and submission into variables
 var searchBoxPlaceholder = document.getElementById('searchInput');
 var searchInput = document.getElementById('searchBox');
 var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');
 
 //Adds class to each search option and puts ID of hidde field into variable
 var searchPrefSubmission = document.getElementsByClassName('buttonSearch');
 var hiddenInput = document.getElementById('searchChoice');
 
 //Global variable to indicate whether searchOptions menu is opened or closed
 var menuToggle = "closed";

 //Closes element when one clicks outside of it.
 function hideOnClickOutside(element) {
  const outsideClickListener = event => {
   if (!element.contains(event.target) && isVisible(element)) { // or use: event.target.closest(selector) === null
     element.style.display = 'none'
     removeClickListener()
   }
  }

  const removeClickListener = () => {
   document.removeEventListener('click', outsideClickListener)
  }

  document.addEventListener('click', outsideClickListener)
 }

 const isVisible = elem => !!elem && !!( elem.offsetWidth || elem.offsetHeight || elem.getClientRects().length )
 
 //When the placeholder box is clicked, the option menu appears
 menuPlaceholder.addEventListener('click', function (event){
  menuDisplay.style.display = "block";
  menuToggle = "open";
  
  //Add click event to searchPref buttons
  for (i = 0; i < searchPrefSubmission.length; i++) {
   //Assigns value of the button to both the hidden input field and the placeholder box
   searchPrefSubmission[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    hiddenInput.value=this.value;
    boxLabel.innerHTML = this.value;
    
    menuDisplay.style.display = "none";
    menuPlaceholder.style.display = "inline-block";
    
   });
  }
  
 }); 
 
 
 //This code causes the text input box of the search form to appear when the background box is clicked
 searchBoxPlaceholder.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  searchInput.style.display = "inline";
  submitButton.style.display = "inline";
  //hideOnClickOutside(menuDisplay);
 });
 
 if (menuToggle == "open"){
  document.body.addEventListener('click', function(event){
   alert('Foo!');
  })
 }else{
  alert('Boo!');
 }
 
 /*function toggleMenu () {
  //menuDisplay.style.display = "none";
  alert('Boo!');
  menuToggle = "closed";
 }*/
```

```css
body {
 font-family:Montserrat, sans-serif;
}

#searchOptionPlaceholder {
 display: inline-block;
}

#searchSelection {
 padding: 10px 20px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 background-color: #F0F3F5;
 display: inline-block;
 color: #000000;
 width: 140px;
 max-width: 200px;
 max-height: 35px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#searchSelection img {
 float: right;
}

#searchLabel {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-top: 10px;
 vertical-align: top;
}

#searchOptions {
 display: none;
 background-color: #F0F3F5;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
}

#searchOptions ul {
 background-color: #F0F3F5;
 padding: 5px;
}

#searchOptions li {
 list-style-type: none;
 border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

#searchOptions li:hover {
 background-color: #706868;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.buttonSearch {
 background-color: transparent;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.searchSubHeading {
 font-size: 12px;
}

#searchInput {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #F0F3F5;
 padding: 10px 100px;
 position: relative;
 top: 0px;
 max-width: 350px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#searchInput img {
 position: relative;
 left: 80px;
}

#searchBox {
 display: none;
 width: 80%;
 background-color: #F0F3F5;
 border: none;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 position: relative;
 right: 50px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#submit {
 border: none;
 background-image: url('https://library.domains.skidmore.edu/search/magnifyingGlass.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: contain;
 width: 50px;
 height: 30px;
 position: relative;
 right: -80px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#otherLinks {
 margin-top: 10px;
}

#otherLinks a{
 color: #000000;
}

#otherLinks a:hover{
 color: #006a52;
}
```

```html
<h1>Library Search</h1>
<form method="post" action="https://library.domains.skidmore.edu/search/searchBox.php" id="librarySearch">
<div id="searchSelection"><span id="searchLabel">Catalog</span><img src="down.png" height="30px" width="30px" /></div>
<div id="searchOptions">
 <ul>
  <li><button type="button" name="searchPref" value="Catalog" class="buttonSearch">Catalog<br /><br /><span class="searchSubHeading">Search books and DVDs</span></button></li>
  <li><button type="button" name="searchPref" value="SearchMore" class="buttonSearch">SearchMore<br /><br /><span class="searchSubHeading">Search everything</span></button></li>
  <li><button type="button" name="searchPref" value="Journals" class="buttonSearch">Journals<br /><br /><span class="searchSubHeading">Search journals</span></button></li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div id="searchInput">
<input type="hidden" id="searchChoice" name="searchPref" value="catalog" />
<input type="search" id="searchBox" size="60" name="searchText" placeholder="Search our holdings"/><button type="submit" id="submit"></button></div>
<div id="otherLinks"><a href="https://lucy2.skidmore.edu/vwebv/searchAdvanced">Advanced Catalog Search |</a><a href="https://lib-proxy01.skidmore.edu/login?url=https://firstsearch.oclc.org/dbname=WorldCat;done=referer;FSIP"> WorldCat |</a><a href="http://libguides.skidmore.edu/c.php?g=35919&amp;p=1378258"> eBooks</a></div>
</form>
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand what your variables are. Could you provide some minimal HTML, and the code that assigns DOM elements to variables? The best would be to create a runnable snippet in your question, that illustrates the problem (use the button on the top bar in the editor).

Comment: Done.  The code is minimal because I am working on a development page.  It will ultimately live in WordPress.  As an aside that is why I am avoiding jQuery.  The theme we are using loads its own version (1.x I believe) and loading a second seems to break things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- Adding event listeners *within* an event listener is in most cases a code smell: this will add those inner listeners *each* time the outer event is triggered. Those listeners remain attached, and so they accumulate. So, attach all event handlers in the top-level script, i.e. on page load, and then never again.
- The `if ... else` at the end will execute on page load, and then never again. So the value of `menuToggle` is guaranteed to be "closed". You need to put that `if...else` switch *inside* the handler, so that it executes every time the event triggers, at which time the `menuToggle` variable will possibly have a modified value.
- The `body` element does not stretch (by default) over the whole window. If you want to detect a click anywhere on the page, you should attach the listener on the `document` element itself, not on `document.body`.
- When the click on the menu placeholder is handled, you should avoid that this event "bubbles" up the DOM tree up to the document, because there you have the other handler that wants to hide the menu again. You can do this with `event.stopPropagation()`.
- The global variable is not absolutely necessary, but if you use it, then I would call it `menuVisible` and give it a boolean value: `false` at first, and possibly `true` later.
- For actually toggling the menu, I would create a function, which takes the desired visibility (`false` or `true`) as argument, and then performs the toggle.
- Do not use undeclared variables, like the `for` loop variable `i`. Define it with `let`.

Here is your code with those changes implemented. Of course, there is still a lot that could be improved, but I believe that goes beyond the scope of this question:

```js
var menuPlaceholder = document.getElementById('searchSelection');
var menuDisplay = document.getElementById('searchOptions');
var boxLabel = document.getElementById('searchLabel');

var searchBoxPlaceholder = document.getElementById('searchInput');
var searchInput = document.getElementById('searchBox');
var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');

var searchPrefSubmission = document.getElementsByClassName('buttonSearch');
var hiddenInput = document.getElementById('searchChoice');

// Changed name and type of global variable:
var menuVisible = false;

// Removed some functions ...

menuPlaceholder.addEventListener('click', function (event){
    // Use new function for actually setting the visibility 
    toggleMenu(!menuVisible);
    // Avoid that click event bubbles up to the document level
    event.stopPropagation();
}); 

// Add these event handlers on page load, not within another handler
// Define loop variable with let
for (let i = 0; i < searchPrefSubmission.length; i++) {
    //Assigns value of the button to both the hidden input field and the placeholder box
    searchPrefSubmission[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        hiddenInput.value = this.value;
        boxLabel.innerHTML = this.value;
        // Use the new function for setting the visibility            
        toggleMenu(false);
        menuPlaceholder.style.display = "inline-block";     
    });
}

searchBoxPlaceholder.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    searchInput.style.display = "inline";
    submitButton.style.display = "inline";
});

// Bind handler on document itself, and call new function
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    toggleMenu(false);
});

// new function to perform the toggle
function toggleMenu(show) {
    menuDisplay.style.display = show ? "block" : "none";
    menuVisible = show;
}
```

```css
body {
 font-family:Montserrat, sans-serif;
}

#searchOptionPlaceholder {
 display: inline-block;
}

#searchSelection {
 padding: 10px 20px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 background-color: #F0F3F5;
 display: inline-block;
 color: #000000;
 width: 140px;
 max-width: 200px;
 max-height: 35px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#searchSelection img {
 float: right;
}

#searchLabel {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-top: 10px;
 vertical-align: top;
}

#searchOptions {
 display: none;
 background-color: #F0F3F5;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
}

#searchOptions ul {
 background-color: #F0F3F5;
 padding: 5px;
}

#searchOptions li {
 list-style-type: none;
 border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

#searchOptions li:hover {
 background-color: #706868;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.buttonSearch {
 background-color: transparent;
 border: none;
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.searchSubHeading {
 font-size: 12px;
}

#searchInput {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #F0F3F5;
 padding: 10px 100px;
 position: relative;
 top: 0px;
 max-width: 350px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#searchInput img {
 position: relative;
 left: 80px;
}

#searchBox {
 display: none;
 width: 80%;
 background-color: #F0F3F5;
 border: none;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 position: relative;
 right: 50px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#submit {
 border: none;
 background-image: url('https://library.domains.skidmore.edu/search/magnifyingGlass.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: contain;
 width: 50px;
 height: 30px;
 position: relative;
 right: -80px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#otherLinks {
 margin-top: 10px;
}

#otherLinks a{
 color: #000000;
}

#otherLinks a:hover{
 color: #006a52;
}
```

```html
<h1>Library Search</h1>
<form method="post" action="https://library.domains.skidmore.edu/search/searchBox.php" id="librarySearch">
    <div id="searchSelection">
        <span id="searchLabel">Catalog</span>
        <img src="down.png" height="30px" width="30px" />
    </div>
    <div id="searchOptions">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <button type="button" name="searchPref" value="Catalog" class="buttonSearch">
                    Catalog<br /><br /><span class="searchSubHeading">Search books and DVDs</span>
                </button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="button" name="searchPref" value="SearchMore" class="buttonSearch">
                    SearchMore<br /><br /><span class="searchSubHeading">Search everything</span>
                </button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="button" name="searchPref" value="Journals" class="buttonSearch">
                    Journals<br /><br /><span class="searchSubHeading">Search journals</span>
                </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="searchInput">
        <input type="hidden" id="searchChoice" name="searchPref" value="catalog" />
        <input type="search" id="searchBox" size="60" name="searchText" placeholder="Search our holdings"/>
        <button type="submit" id="submit"></button>
    </div>
    <div id="otherLinks">
        <a href="https://lucy2.skidmore.edu/vwebv/searchAdvanced">Advanced Catalog Search |</a>
        <a href="https://lib-proxy01.skidmore.edu/login?url=https://firstsearch.oclc.org/dbname=WorldCat;done=referer;FSIP"> WorldCat |</a>
        <a href="http://libguides.skidmore.edu/c.php?g=35919&amp;p=1378258"> eBooks</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This is very helpful.  Thanks!  Other than the need to click the menu twice when the page first loads, it accomplishes exactly what I need it to do.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue you mention. In the runnable snippet I posted in my answer you only need to click once. Possibly some other code you have is responsible for that.